# Elucidating the nature of infinite dedekind finite subsets in the reals

Tags: set-theory, infinity, axiom-of-choice, constructive-mathematics

Criteria for "constructive" in this question: Given a formal system and all the models that satisfy the axiomatic systems of interest (e.g. all models of ZF without choice), any object being constructed can be proved to exist/not exist and the proof is written only in terms of the sequence of axioms (and theorems derived from them) being used, and rejecting the law of excluded middle.

In ZF set theory where axiom of choice is absent, it is consistent that there exists amorphous and infinite dedekind finite sets, although we cannot prove them because we can construct models where they exist and models where they don't.

> $S$ is infinite dedekind finite, or strictly dedekind finite if it does not biject with any initial section of the naturals (not of finite cardinality) and there exists no map that can inject $S$ into any of its subsets.

In particular, it is consistent that there can exist infinite dedekind finite subsets $S$ of the reals.

After discussing in the chat, it was found that $S \subsetneq \Bbb{R\setminus Q}$ and that $S$ consists of both a countable subset and another infinite dedekind finite set.

But that raised a question: It is known that any irrational $r$ is a rational distance away from some other irrationals $s$, therefore this will mean for any subset of irrationals, there always exists a nonzero rational $q$, not necessary unique, such that $s=r+q$ for any pairs of $r,s \in S$. Since $\Bbb{Q}$ is countable regardless of choice, it seems $\{s : s=r+q\}$ will always form a countable subset for any candidate $S$, thus leading to the conclusion that there cannot be any such $S$.

> 1. What is an explicit example of an infinite dedekind finite subset of the reals in models of ZF where they can be proved to exist. More generally, what well known models of ZF will allow the existence of such sets be provable and also constructible explcitly via an algorithm or procedure?
> 2. How to show that objects defined using both axiom of choice or its negation can never be constructive, is there a well known reference for such proof?

Comment: "*In ZF set theory where axiom of choice is absent, there exists amorphous and infinite dedekind finite sets.*", no, ZF is syntax and existence is semantics. Moreover, this seems to hint that the existence of DF sets is provable without choice, which it most certainly isn't. Even rejecting countable choice doesn't necessarily mean that you can prove there are DF sets.

Comment: Also, you keep writing $\Bbb{R/Q}$, but I think you mean $\Bbb{R\setminus Q}$.

Comment: The three questions, overall, seem to be quite confused upon first reading, specifically about what the nature of sets of reals in a universe of set theory, and what does mean to have an explicit construction. The third question starts with a blatantly false statement, and also seems to be very confused. Using the negation of AC is the same as using AC. And the set {x : x=0 and CH holds or x=1 and CH fails} does not use the axiom of choice, is provably a singleton, but requires the LEM in order to be determined in full. Since you cannot constructively tell me its element.

Comment: "$S$ consists of both a countable subset and another infinite dedekind finite set." What? Any set with a countably infinite subset is not Dedekind finite ...

Comment: It was brought to my attention that instead of interacting with my comments, you posted them on the chat and had a small interaction there with someone. Did that help to dispel some of the problems? Do you feel that your questions have been answered (or alternatively, that some significant edits should be made in order for the question to be less "confused by foundations and related terminology")? It is just common courtesy to reply to someone that tried to give some critique to your question (and definitely not in a bad way)...

Comment: @AsafKaragila I was taught in physics stack exchange that edits to the main post are preferred when it comes to addressing the comments, which is why in the edit above, I actually incorporated the 3 points you raised above. I thought the SE system will notify the users about the question is being edited, but I guess I was wrong, I should have posted a comment to you that I have made the edits in response to your comments. As for the edits due to later interactions in chat (such as the sentence added in the edit: "because we can construct models where they exist and models where they don't."),

Comment: Alessandro in the chat is actually answering a question of mine that is more general than Q2 in the current version of the edit, which is on provability in general, and it just happens that his answer applied to this OP here which is why the edit is included. I am sorry that it seems as if I have ignored your comments, but I actually have incoporated them into my edits. So to answer your most recent comment: 1. Yes, you, Noah, and alessandro have dispelled some of the problems 2. The question was already edited to incorporate the points raised.

Comment: As for whether the question is adequately answered after the edit, while I do have some progress in finding a model https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.1957, I am wondering if there are other examples. Also I have still yet to locate any proof of the nonconstructibility objects using the axiom of choice and its negation, though that question might be poorly asked because my set theory background is not very stable and result in some confusions

Comment: @NoahSchweber Relevant conversation here https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40542676#40542676, I think I have missread alessandro's as "The irrationals wil contain a countable set, *of which* it has a subset X that has no countable subset" I also found that weird and has the same question as you when you first read it, but because that's what I thought I read and not realising I misread it, I end up stating that in the OP

Comment: @Secret OK, there's a few things going on here. First of all, what that line is saying is: the rationals have a (in fact, lots) countably infinite subset. This is just **true**, provably in ZF: e.g. $\{\sqrt{n}: n$ is prime$\}$ is a countably infinite subset of the irrationals. It is*also* true that if $D$ is infinite Dedekind-finite, then $D\cap\{$irrationals$\}$ is infinite Dedekind-finite since $D\cap C$ is finite whenever $C$ is countable and an infinite Dedekind-finite set minus a finite set is still infinite Dedekind-finite. (cont'd)

Comment: Meanwhile, the comment "There can be such subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, but not the irrationals" means: there can (consistently with ZF) be infinite Dedekind-finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, but the irrationals cannot be such a set" - not "... but the irrationals cannot **contain** such a set." Finally, no, there are no "simply definable" infinite Dedekind-finite sets; this can be made precise via [descriptive set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_set_theory). In particular, the simplest we can do is [this](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/res/ded.pdf) (due to Arnie Miller).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as constructivity, Arnie Miller has a proof that it is consistent to have a Borel set which is [infinite] Dedekind-finite.

> *Miller, Arnold W.*, [**A Dedekind finite Borel set**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00153-010-0195-6), Arch. Math. Logic 50, No. 1-2, 1-17 (2011). [ZBL1225.03061](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1225.03061).

In fact this Borel set is relatively low in the hierarchy, it is an $F_{\sigma\delta}$ set.

As far as "constructive", I guess this is more or less the best you can get. In the same paper he shows that it's impossible to get it from a lower stage of the Borel hierarchy.

If this answer does not satisfy you, then I'm afraid that there isn't much more we can say. Let me explain why by answering the second answer.

Suppose that $\varphi(x)$ is some formula which defines a set. And now you want to ask if the set it defines is provably such and such. For example, is it provably a finite set of ordinals, or provably a set of reals (for some canonical coding of the reals into sets).

Some formulas define things like that. Like the set of rational numbers, or the set of reals which are constructible in Gödel's sense.

But now we run into independence. In some models, we can show that no formula defines a Dedekind-finite set (or some other set whose existence defies the axiom of choice). Simply because in those models the axiom of choice holds, or sufficient fragment of it holds. And in some models we can prove that a certain set with a certain property does in fact exist.

This means that it is impossible, without the axiom of choice, to prove or disprove that $\varphi(x)$ defines a set with a certain property.

And it can get worse. Just assuming the failure of the axiom of choice, we can prove that Zorn's lemma fails. But we cannot point at a specific example, since the axiom of choice consistently holds up to some rank in the universe, and only fails very high. So anything you might want to define and prove that it "has to be a counterexample to Zorn's lemma" is going to fail.

In other words, the definitions "$\alpha$ is the least such that $V_\alpha$ is not well-orderable" and "$\alpha$ is the least ordinal such that $\mathcal P(\alpha)$ is not well-orderable" might be such that just assuming choice fails ensures that this $\alpha$ exists; but there is no algorithm for finding it, because we can always find models where choice fails *above* this $\alpha$. And the same is true for many other definitions of this sort.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and guidance. This will surely help me to be aware on how to check whether an object is constructive, predicative or nonconstructive, which will be useful when working in constructive and/or predicative mathematics and in determining whether it is possible to find (counter)examples to some given formula algorithmically